# Python: How to print coordinates (row, column) of a string in a file?

Tags: python, string, file, search

How to print coordinates of a string in a file?

I have a large file with only one occurence of a string. How do I print out its starting coordinates (the row and column it starts on) in a tuple (or a list or anything)?

I've already done:

```
f = open('text.txt', 'r')
text = f.read()
```

Now what?

PS: I know this is terribly basic, but nothing seems to have worked and this is not in any basic tutorial that I could find.

Comment: Can you post the sample data of your `text.txt` file?

Comment: +Sijan Bhandari I'm sorry, I can't, it's private. They are about 50 rows and 50 columns (roughly) of ASCII characters. I could generate some spoof data, but I don't see why it is necessary.

Comment: To clarify - I'm positive there is only one occurence of a given string (say: "aaaaa") in the file (based on search through an editor). Now I want Python to find it again and print the coordinates so I can move forward with my coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
def find_coordinates(string, filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        for row, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
            col = line.find(string)
            if col > -1:
                return row, col + 1

coordinates = find_coordinates('aaaaa', '/path/to/file')  # returns (row, col)
```

Comment: This is it, thank you! Also, I thought there would be something premade for this, that's why I was getting frustrated :).

Answer (score 0):

If your 'text.txt' file has coordinates in lines you can use  this.

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

Comment: "content"? What is that? How to do this with a concrete string (say "aaa")?

Comment: `content` would be, in this case, a list of the lines on the file